# Lightning Action showing in Feed instead of header

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, service-cloud-console

I am trying to place a lightning action in a Console App using a lightning component.  Every time I add the action to "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" in the page layout instead of getting a button at the top right of the screen, it is being placed in the Case feed. I have a quick fix of using a standard button which is calling a VFP with the component on it but that is creating a horrible UI.

Here is where I want the button (Lightning action) to go.  This is currently the button calling the VFP:
[image]

But Here is where it is going:[image]

The component is using implements="force:lightningQuickAction" 
( this is also happening outside the console app as well)

Is there a work around to this? or is this an issue just for the Case object?

Comment: There are always some buttons that only appear in chatter tab, some always appear in the activity tab, others appear as buttons - you cannot change the standard behavior, see `Actions on Record Pages` here: [Understand How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_actions)

Comment: This happens if Feed Tracking is enabled for the object in question (just ran into this issue myself).